# How to instantiate a class derived from a abstract class

Tags: c++

```
template<class Elem>
class BinNode//Binary tree node abstract class.
{
public:
    virtual Elem& val() = 0;//return the node's element;
    virtual void setVal(const Elem& ) = 0;//set the node's element;
    virtual BinNode* left() const = 0;//return the node's left child;
    virtual BinNode* right() const = 0;//return the node's right child;
    virtual void setLeft(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's left child's element;
    virtual void setRight(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's right child's element;
};

template<class Elem>
class BinNodePtr:public BinNode<Elem>
{
public:
    Elem ele;//the content of the node
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* lc;//the node's left child
    BinNodePtr<Elem>* rc;//the node's right child
public:
    static int now_on;//the node's identifier
    BinNodePtr(){lc = rc = NULL;ele = 0;};//the constructor
    ~BinNodePtr(){};//the destructor
    void setVal(const Elem& e){this->ele = e;};
    Elem& val(){return ele;}//return the element of the node
    inline BinNode<Elem>* left()const//return the node's left child
    {
        return lc;
    }
    inline BinNode<Elem>* right()const//return the node's right child
    {
        return rc;
    }
    void setLeft(const Elem& e){lc->ele = e;}//to set the content of the node's leftchild
    void setRight(const Elem& e){rc->ele = e;}//to set the content of the node's rightchild
};

int main()
{
    BinNodePtr<int> root;//initiate a variable//the error is here.
    BinNodePtr<int> subroot = &root;//initiate a pointer to the variable
}
```

When I build it , the compiler told me that "cannot instantiate abstract class". And the error is at BinNodePtr root; I'm not instantiating an abstract class but a class derived from an abstract class.How can I solve it ?

Comment: You defined `setLeft` and `setRight` with different parameters in `BinNodePtr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In abstract class.

```
virtual void setLeft(**BinNode***) = 0;//set the node's left child's element;
virtual void setRight(**BinNode***) = 0;//set the node's right child's element;
```

and in derived class

```
void setLeft(const **Elem**& e){lc->ele = e;}
void setRight(const **Elem**& e){rc->ele = e;}
```

Function signature doesn't match..

Comment: To help detect this error you can write the word `override` after your function headers in derived class, if they are supposed to be overrides. Then the compiler will give an error exactly on those lines if they signatures do not match.

Answer (score 1):

The following two methods are not defined:

```
virtual void setLeft(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's left child's element;
virtual void setRight(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's right child's element;
```

Because the defined methods in `BinNodePtr` have different parameters:

```
void setLeft(const Elem& e){lc->ele = e;}
void setRight(const Elem& e){rc->ele = e;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't implement these pure virtual functions

```
virtual void setLeft(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's left child's element;
virtual void setRight(BinNode*) = 0;//set the node's right child's element;
```

So the class `BinNodePtr` is an abstract class.
And there is an import rule: you can instantiate an abstract class, that say you can't create an class object using abstract class.

you can read this [article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/):